# How i can customize scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to customize the scroll bar in div. I've used the following code to change it. But I had no idea how to change the scroll buttons and didn't get the result I wanted
In addition, it does not work in Mozilla Firefox browser.
What I Want:

[image]

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 3px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #888;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
```

Comment: share your code. @zharf pzh

Answer (score 1):

Firefox implementet [partial support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-color) for custom scrollbars in v64.

```css
.your-div-selector {
    scrollbar-color: #0a4c95 #c2d2e4; /* Track color and thumb color */
}
```

If you want a consistent styling like in your sketch, I would recommend a third-party JavaScript option like https://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/ (there are many).

Comment: thanks..Do you can see my image? How I customize handle?

Comment: Yes, and it's currently not possible to achieve with pure CSS across browsers. You can change the color of the "track" and the "thumb" for the scrollbar, and perhaps the width of the scrollbar. More than that would require JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define class or id for that div and then add CSS classes to that specific div:

```
#MY-div-id::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 3px;
}

#MY-div-id::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background: #888;
}

#MY-div-id::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background: #888;
}

#MY-div-id::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
background: #555;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is nearly matching code with css. You just have to change the color and the image in  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb try small image and you may also need to adjust the position.

```css
 .container {
      margin: 40px auto;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .container::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 20px;
    }
    .container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: tomato;
      border-left: 9px solid white;
      border-right: 9px solid white;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-image:url( http://i.imgur.com/ygGobeC.png);
    }
    .container .item {
      height: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      background: silver;
    }
    .container .item:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    } 
    .container {
        direction:rtl;
      }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
```